# Convertendo String em ArrayList

Tags: java, array, string, arraylist

Estou recebendo no meu código java uma variável com o seguinte valor

```
String arquivo = "CNPJ;INSCRICAOESTADUAL;COD_IBGE;DT_OPE;VLR_CARTAO_CRED;VLR_CARTAO_DEB
35083840049;0;4312476;13/01/2018;0.00;66.00
35083840049;0;4312476;18/01/2018;33.00;26.00
35083840049;0;4312476;19/01/2018;0.00;38.40
35083840049;0;4312476;20/01/2018;0.00;55.00
35083840049;0;4312476;21/01/2018;59.80;0.00
35083840049;0;4312476;31/01/2018;0.00;122.00
91589507000854;3770005769;4312476;02/01/2018;2492.59;2742.34
91589507000854;3770005769;4312476;03/01/2018;1333.95;1686.86"
```

porém, quero jogar esses valores num array onde, respectivamente, `CNPJ`é  `35083840049` `INSCRICAOESTADUAL` é `0` e assim sucessivamente com os demais valores.

Ao debugar o código vi que estou tendo o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ou seja, ele está montando um array com todo o resultado.

Estou usando este método:

```
     String arquivo = arquivoDecodificado;
        String[] items = arquivo.split(";");
        List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String item : items) {
           itemList.add(item);
        }
        System.out.println(itemList);
```

Como posso fazer para deixar da forma que eu preciso ??

Comment: Não seria mais fácil ler linha a linha um arquivo .csv e fazer um ArrayList do objeto com os campos?

Comment: @GustavoFragoso  tem algum exemplo para mostrar ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posso sugerir que você mova esses dados para um arquivo csv e em seguida use o seguinte código:

**Usando scanner:**

```
try {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("src/arquivo.csv"));
    // Delimitador dos dados
    scanner.useDelimiter(";");

    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        System.out.print(scanner.next() + " | ");
    }
    scanner.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

A saída será a seguinte:

```
CNPJ | INSCRICAOESTADUAL | COD_IBGE | DT_OPE | VLR_CARTAO_CRED | VLR_CARTAO_DEB
35083840049 | 0 | 4312476 | 13/01/2018 | 0.00 | 66.00
35083840049 | 0 | 4312476 | 18/01/2018 | 33.00 | 26.00
35083840049 | 0 | 4312476 | 19/01/2018 | 0.00 | 38.40
35083840049 | 0 | 4312476 | 20/01/2018 | 0.00 | 55.00
35083840049 | 0 | 4312476 | 21/01/2018 | 59.80 | 0.00
35083840049 | 0 | 4312476 | 31/01/2018 | 0.00 | 122.00
91589507000854 | 3770005769 | 4312476 | 02/01/2018 | 2492.59 | 2742.34
91589507000854 | 3770005769 | 4312476 | 03/01/2018 | 1333.95 | 1686.86 |
```

**Usando BufferedReader:**

```
try(BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/arquivo.csv"))) {

    String line;

    while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        // String [] dados = line.split(";"); // Necessário para separar os dados
        System.out.println(line);
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Saída:

```
35083840049;0;4312476;13/01/2018;0.00;66.00
35083840049;0;4312476;18/01/2018;33.00;26.00
35083840049;0;4312476;19/01/2018;0.00;38.40
35083840049;0;4312476;20/01/2018;0.00;55.00
35083840049;0;4312476;21/01/2018;59.80;0.00
35083840049;0;4312476;31/01/2018;0.00;122.00
91589507000854;3770005769;4312476;02/01/2018;2492.59;2742.34
91589507000854;3770005769;4312476;03/01/2018;1333.95;1686.86
```

Dai basta que você construa seu objeto dentro do while.

Obs.: Pule uma linha se os dados estiverem com cabeçalho.

Fontes:

http://www.java67.com/2015/08/how-to-load-data-from-csv-file-in-java.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274259/read-csv-with-scanner

Comment: Por curiosidade, há alguma forma de se fazer isso no java7/8  sem utilizar scanner?

Comment: Fiz uma pesquisa e editei com mais um formato @Articuno. Aproveitei pra colocar as referências.